# I got a error while running server in django i was using git before

Tags: python-3.x, django

```
bibek@sweety-babe:~/Desktop/Friends$ python3 manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/bibek/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration base.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')
```

i am getting this error suddenly after git push. I dont know what is the reason behind this please help me.

this is just dummy (The POST method is used to send data to the server to create/update a resource on the server. In this HTTP POST request example, the Content-Type request header indicates the data type in the body of the POST message, and the Content-Length request header indicates the size of the data in the body of the POST request. The sample data is listed in the Content tab, and additional headers are listed in the Headers tab. The data is sent to the server in the body of the POST message.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you probably didn't track the migration file when pushing, try pulling and see. if it doesn't work then I suggest you delete the files in the migration folder apart from the init file then run make migrations again

Comment: Yah, it looks like a migration wasn't made at some point.